# Will checking if the number is even (of course > 2) before checking if it is a prime number increase the performance?

Tags: c++, performance, primes

Well, the question explains it all, still I will elaborate with some code. In a nutshell: Which of the 2 codes is better? :

Code 1:

> check for num==2 and num==1 ;)

```
if(num%2) {
    checkPrime(num) //function definition not needed
}
else {
    //not prime
}
```

---

Code 2:

> check for num==2 and num==1 ;)

```
if(isPrime(num)) {
    //prime
}
else {
    //not prime
}
```

---

> Neither `checkPrime` not `isPrime` checks for evenness

Comment: The best way to find out is to measure the difference yourself

Comment: It depends entirely on how your `checkPrime` or `isPrime` function is implemented. If it's trial division starting from 2, then the difference will be very small. If it's some other prime test that takes a long time for even numbers, adding the check will make things faster.

Comment: About the *"Neither checkPrime not isPrime checks for evenness"*, are you sure? How are those functions implemented? Is it possible that you are supposed to just *skip* (without testing) the even numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple `isPrime()` function I use something like the following pseudocode:

```
isPrime(num)

  // Negatives, 0, 1 are not prime.
  if (num < 2)
    return false
  endif

  // 2 is the only even prime.
  if (num MOD 2 == 0)
    return (num == 2)
  endif

  // Try odd divisors.
  limit = 1 + sqrt(num)
  for (i <- 3 to limit step 2)
    if (num MOD i == 0)
      return false
    endif
  endfor

  // If we get this far, the number is prime.
  return true

end isPrime
```

Answer (score 0):

All the logic of checking if a number is prime should be contained in the function. Your first option makes no sense because of this.

Your second option is also non-optimal because checking for evenness is an optimization to the simple classical primality test algorithm I suppose you are referring to, so that check should be inside the function as part of the algorithm itself.

There are a few optimizations can can be done to the classical algorithm, one of them being checking for evenness, but all of that should be done in the function.

That being said, if the concern is performance, please be aware that there are some situational faster but significantly more complicated algorithms.